# AWS - Disconnected : No supported authentication methods available (server sent :publickey)

Tags: putty, amazon-web-services

I am facing the issue in connecting server via putty. The error is showing me is "Server Refused our key: AWS - Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent:publickey)".

I am logging in with username " ubuntu ".I checked lots of websites but I didn't find any solution. I create a new key-pair file( .pem ) and tried again that's also is not working.
I am using the same key name for the pem file. Then using pem file I am creating a ppk  file and then it is not working

Comment: Well did you add the key to the server configuration?

Comment: Where did you create the new key-pair ? AWS will create a new one for you while spinning a new instance. Download it, convert it to ppk then use it with Putty

Comment: @Algeriassic I did that but still, it's giving me error for the key "Server refused our key"

Comment: @Seth where to add in server configuration, I created with the same name as i have used in instance

Comment: It's not the name it's the actual key that is important.

Comment: @Seth Yes Seth I am telling that I have created key with the same name as I have used in the instance

Comment: @DebashishDwivedi what OS are you using? Ubuntu or Amazon Linux? If it's Amazon Linux, the user would be ec2-user not ubuntu

Comment: @Seth I am using windows 10 and I have used both the username ubuntu andec2-user

Comment: @DebashishDwivedi He means what OS is the AWS instance. Use this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-key-pair to create a new keyfile for your Amazon instance and download it. Then convert that to a ppk. I'm assuming you're making an EC2 instance here, but you need to specify, if the VM operating system (that you are connecting to, not Windows 10 that you are using) is Ubuntu or some form of Debian, use ubuntu as the user, otherwise ec2 for Amazon Linux. A PEM file is a file that has a sort of password that only the people with the file know.

Answer (score 1):

When we convert your `.pem` file to `.ppk` it creates a public and private key of it's own inside the `.ppk` file like this:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: imported-openssh-key
Public-Lines: 6
AAAA***
***
***
***
...
Private-Lines: 14
AAA***
***
***
***
...
Private-MAC: ***
```

To connect to the server, you need to append the *six lines of public key* above into `authorized_keys` file in server user's `/home/.ssh` directory.

**Note:** Make sure the syntax is correct in `authorized_keys` file. For *rsa* keys it is like this:

`ssh-rsa AAA***(whole public key in one line without pressing enter)***`

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, I decided to look at the public key for the root user, it had the following appearance "rsa-ssh YOUR KEY name of .pem file" in one line, the public key generated by the putty from .pem for the new user looked different: the comments and the key were written in about 6 lines when I edited the putty key as root and copied it in /nome/nevuser/.ssh/authorizade_key it work

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-key-pair

You have an EC2 instance it looks like, follow the instructions above to create a key pair for this instance. A PEM file is a form of password that is shared by only those who have the files configured. You have to create this on the EC2 instance in Amazon, so the EC2 knows that those who connect with this file are authorized, and then download it to your own computer, and convert it to something Putty can use.

Then, determine what operating system your EC2 instance is using. Depending on what it is, you will use a different user, for example with Ubuntu, the user is ubuntu, or Amazon Linux, the user is ec2.

Answer (score 0):

AWS – Disconnected : No supported authentication methods available (server sent :publickey)
x

1.After uploading *pem file dont click on generate  public or private key pair.

2. Just click on save private key

3.Just upload this file in auth, this will solve above issue

Please on this link for further details
https://computerlogics931.blogspot.com/2018/04/aws-disconnected-no-supported.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The link you included has no further details- did you mean that was the source of the above instructions?